# Simple Linq to XML query not working on MSTest file (*.trx)

Tags: linq-to-xml, mstest

I can't see why this query isn't working.

```
Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(file));
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
var res = from o in doc.Descendants("Counters")
          select new 
          {
              Total = (string)o.Attribute("total"),
              Executed = (string)o.Attribute("executed"),
              Passed = (string)o.Attribute("passed"),
              Failed = (string)o.Attribute("failed")
          };

Assert.IsTrue(res.Count() > 0);
```

I have checked and double checked that the file is a .trx file.  I am having a brain fart or is there something i'm missing?

Thanks, Bill

Comment: Have you tried debug that test method and check if XDocument is Loaded successfully?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for a query not finding elements is a default namespace in the XML not taken into account when querying to try whether

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
XNamespace df = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
var res = from o in doc.Descendants(df + "Counters")
          select new 
          {
              Total = (string)o.Attribute("total"),
              Executed = (string)o.Attribute("executed"),
              Passed = (string)o.Attribute("passed"),
              Failed = (string)o.Attribute("failed")
          };
```

gives you the result you are looking for. If not then post a sample of the XML.